# How to show the last item in listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to show or focus of the listview to last item

I use this to get that last position to show the last item in listview

```
lv_list.setSelection(lv_list.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
```

But when there are images in last positions the listview is not focusing the last item instead it focus on the last but one or the previous one.

How to focus the listview even if there are images in the last positions

[image: The emulator image is like this]

Comment: after press enter????

Comment: set selection in listview onclick and then base adapter class u have to write follwing condtion if(selectedpotion == arraylist.size) hight light color of row

Comment: `if(selectedpotion == arraylist.size)` where i have to write this condition in adapter @prakash

Comment: @PiyushGupta  am getting arraylist from service so after press enter it takes time to load those images. Then if there are no images its working properly but if there are images its not taking to last position

Comment: see here http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2009/12/android-selected-state-listview-example/

Comment: yes you have to check the condtion in adapter .. row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);

Comment: @prakash I am trying to show the last item not the focusing the item in listview after click. Sorry i edited my question

Comment: in getview method take the postion put this condition if(postion==array.size)